# Django CharField option to ensure only one value is stored

Tags: django, django-models

I am working with the following code:

```
class UserDescription(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    # profilePic = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="avatar.png")
    city=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    occupation=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    shortdescription=models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
```

Is there an option using `CharField` such that every time the update in the model happens only the last value stays. i.e. previous values get overwritten.

Comment: Fields all time stored last updated value. Do you want anything else? please clarify

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Can you please explain what you mean ? I want to make sure that only last updated value is stored. i.e. only 1 value stored even after 10th edit.

Comment: For example `country` field. If you update `country` field value then this field only keep the latest value, not old values. If your question indicates another thing please explain more, most probably I can't understand your question.

Comment: Please show sample data. What do you mean by _prevoius values_, how can there be a plural number of values in a row's char column? How do you check that it is not "overwritten"?

Comment: @shafik that is where I was wrong. I assumed it keeps all values.